# How do you find the intersection of these two trig curves?

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, coordinate-systems, trigonometric-series

How do you find the intersection of these two trig curves?

$
\cos(x_1) + \cos(x_2) + \cos(x_3) = 1 \\
\sin(x_1) + \sin(x_2) + \sin(x_3) = 0 
$

Alternatively, how would you find a general solution for $n$ variables (see below)? Would it be easier to solve this in a different coordinate system?

$
\cos(x_1) + \cos(x_2) + \cdots +  \cos(x_n) = 1 \\
\sin(x_1) + \sin(x_2) + \cdots + \sin(x_n) = 0 
$

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hint : $e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x$

Comment: multiply the second equation by *i* and then add to the first? @cosmo5

Comment: Yes. Rest I leave to you.